# How to drag an UITableViewCell horizontally on the left side?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to recreate the `delete` function that we can activate on `UITableViewCell` but instead to have it on the right side, I would like to have it on the left side (hint my reason why to recreate it).

So I added an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on each cells and I implemented those two delegate methods:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
}

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let cell = gestureRecognizer.view!
        if gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let translation = (gestureRecognizer as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).translationInView(cell.superview!)
            if abs(translation.x) > abs(translation.y) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
}
```

Then I implemented the action handling the pan:

```
func rightPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var cellFrame = sender.view!.frame

    let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view!.superview!)

    switch sender.state {
    case .Began:
        println("Started")
    case .Changed:
        cellFrame.origin.x = translation.x

        println("Changed")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

And when I try to drag a cell, I can see "Started" and "Changed" in the logs but nothing happens on the screen. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the frame, not the origin.
Before doing anything, save the initial origin x.
Then, in your `.Changed` case, you can:

```
let newFrame = CGRect(originX + translation.x, cellFrame.origin.y, cellFrame.size.width, cellFrame.size.height)
// then set your new frame..
cellFrame.frame = newFrame
```

Also, you probably want to add the translation value. That `translation.x` represents the distance moved, not the position exactly.

Comment: actually my main problem was that I thought (wrongly, java habits...) that the frame was an object... And the `translation.x` represent the total distance moved, so adding every time the `originX` makes it wrong. I guess you have to put the `originX` somewhere probably in `.Began``